# EF Core Linq Join with OR condition using Method Systax

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

**How can I make this into a single query?**

```
var result1 = await _dbContext.Emails.Join(_dbContext.Sms,
                                    pn => pn.PNID,
                                    sms => sms.From_PNID.Value,
                                    (pn, sms) => new { sms, pn });


var resut2 = await _dbContext.Emails.Join(_dbContext.Sms,
                                    pn => pn.PNID,
                                    sms => sms.To_PNID.Value,
                                    (pn, sms) => new { sms, pn });
```

Want to have like ON `pn.PNID == sms.To_PNID OR pn.PNID == sms.From_PNID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do it using `SelectMany` extension method:

```
var result1 = await  dbContext.Emails
                    .SelectMany(e=>dbContext.Sms.Where(s=>e.PNID==From_PNID.Value 
                                                       || e.PNID==To_PNID.Value)
                                                .Select(e=>new {Email=e,SMS=s})).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks octavioccl, works like magic

Comment: perfect!! Good to know ;)

Answer (score 0):

LINQ Inner Join with OR condition Example::

```
             var q= await  dbContext.Emails
             .SelectMany(e=>dbContext.Sms.Where(s=>e.PNID==From_PNID.Value 
                                    || e.PNID==To_PNID.Value)
                                    .Select(e=>new {Email=e,SMS=s})).ToListAsync();
```

try this example!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use conventional LINQ instead of LINQ expression.

e.g.

```
     var records = (from recordA in TableA 
                    from recordB in TableB 
                    where recordA.Column_1 == recordB.Column_1 || recordA.Column_2 == recordB.Column_2
                   ).ToList();
```

Comment: My team wants to use method expression instead of query expression.

Comment: this query will generate an sql cross join